# ElasticSearch- "No query registered for..."

Tags: search, indexing, elasticsearch

ElasticSearch returns me *"No query registered for [likes_count]"* error when trying to look up entries using the following query. The field *likes_count* is a new field of documents and does not exist in every document.

The same query works without the sort part.

Why does this error appear?

Thanks

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "query_string": {
          "fields": ["description"],
          "query": "sun"
        },
        "sort": [{
          "likes_count": {
            "unmapped_type": "boolean",
            "order": "desc",
            "missing": "_last"
          }
        }]
      },
      "filter": {"term": {"permissions": 1}}
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write your query like this, i.e. `sort` needs to go to the top-level and not nested in the `query`part:

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "query_string": {
          "fields": [
            "description"
          ],
          "query": "sun"
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "permissions": 1
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "likes_count": {
        "unmapped_type": "boolean",
        "order": "desc",
        "missing": "_last"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```